# How do I Update/Refresh QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

I have a QTableView set similar to [this](http://toolz.googlecode.com/svn-history/r107/trunk/GCAlign/tableSortTest.py)

It works fine in the **init**, proper showing the elements, but I can't find a way to update if I change the datain, I wonder how can I send a dataChange signal, I tried creating a class method in the MyTableModel to handle dataChange.emit, but I didn't understand it very well.

```
Class Main
    [...]  #general stuff(init,other objects...)
    self.table = QtGui.QTableView()


    def table_data(*args):
        self.table_data = getdatasomewhereelse()
        return self.table_data


    self.table_model = MyTableModel(table_data(), ['col1', 'col2', self)
    self.table.setModel(self.table_model)


    def delentry():
        dosomethingwithdata()  #i'm using a pickle file to store it, so I have to go back and forth in it


    self.btn_delentry = QtGui.QPushButton()
    self.btn_delentry.clicked.connect(delentry)


class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    [...] # I'm using the same code for this Class as http://toolz.googlecode.com/svn-history/r107/trunk/GCAlign/tableSortTest.py


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    try:
        data = pickle.load(open("data.p", "rb"))
        main = Main()
        main.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    finally:
        pickle.dump(acc, open("data.p", "wb"))
```

I've manage to change the data and it be updated in the table, but there's a nasty bit, the user have to click anywhere to see the result.

Here's what I did.

Set a **call** function similatar to the **init** MyTableModel, like so:

```
def __call__(self, datain, headerdata, QObject,parent=None, *args):
    QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.arraydata = datain
    self.headerdata = headerdata
```

made a custom connect() signal in the button, like so:

```
self.btn_delentry.connect(self.btn_delentry,QtCore.SIGNAL('Ping')
                          ,lambda:self.table_model(
                           self.table_data(), ['name', 'balance'],self.table_name,self))
```

and set to emit() the signal in the delentry() like this:

```
self.btn_delentry.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('Ping'))
```

Now I just want to avoid having to click in anywhere to refresh it.

Comment: Updated the question with some code.

Comment: 1) Have you read these? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html 2) why are you using `__call__` instead of a normal method? 3) Are you emitting any of these signals built into `QAbstractTableModel`\`QAbstractItemModel`? The point of some of them is to tell the view that the model has changed... http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#signals